# Proportional editing not working

Tags: modeling, proportional-editing

I am having an issue where no matter where i click on the sphere while using proportional editing it will grab onto the entire sphere and ot the vertex i have selected that i want to eddit. I just want to grab into the vertex i have selected.

I have one vertex selected i want to use the sphere on connected geometry. 
But the entire sphere moves. 
Please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe proportional size is too big, use mousewheel to control it

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!  I was really lost my mind for about a good ten minutes. That was exactly the issue.